# Add categories to Outlook calendar hover preview

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

Is it possible to add categories to the hover preview in outlook calendar.

Comment: Hover preview? What is that? Screenshots are a good thing to include. Also, please tell us what research you have done and what you have tried so far. Use the EDIT button to improve your question.

Comment: It has been a while and I am writing to see how things are going on with this issue. Have you had a chance to check the replies provided? Any update would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the calendar Peek view?
[image]

If so,  as shown in the below figure, the category can be displayed.

If not, agree with music2myear, please provide a screenshot about "hover preview " for our better research.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.